# html table row get cell values

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Can anyone help me here about getting the data inside the table cell to be inserted to the MySQL Database?

my code to display tables in html is this. i want now to get the values inside a row by clicking the 'Insert' and submit to submituser.php. help pls.

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from tbluser");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo'<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['$contact'].'</td>
<td><a href="submituser.php">Insert</a></td>
';
}

?>
```

Output is like this:

```
| Name | Address | Contact | Action|
|myname|anywhere | 090231  | Insert|
```

Insert code in html

```
<td><a href="submitdata.php">Insert</a></td>
```

`submitdata.php` Must have this code

```
$query = insert into tbluser(name, address, contact) values('cellvalue1','cellvalue2','cellvalue3');
```

Does anyone know how to?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Have you got a form, do you need to parse another HTML page?

Comment: yes sir. i want to parse it to another page. the values in the selected row value must be send to another .php page.

Comment: Could you give us the full page that you need to parse?

Comment: wait sir. ill edit my post.

Comment: done editting. can you try.

Comment: Well, to generate the table you need to have the data already in the MySQL table. So what's the point of parsing it and putting it back in? BTW this is vulnerable to persistent XSS attacks.

Comment: because i want to insert it to another table. you know how to do it?

Comment: Well why don't you do something like this: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1487/copy-an-existing-mysql-table-to-a-new-table/

Comment: im not actually just copying the the values but i also update some of its attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using JQuery:

Change table cells to:

```
<td class="nameCell">myname</td>
<td class="addressCell">anywhere</td>
<td class="contactCell">090231</td>
<td><a href="#" class="insertButton">Insert</a></td>
```

Attach event handler to handle click event in javascript/jquery:

```
$(".insertButton").click(function () {
    var name = $(this).parent().siblings(".nameCell").text();
    var address = $(this).parent().siblings(".addressCell").text();
    var contact = $(this).parent().siblings(".contactCell").text();

    //now call your api and pass the data
    $.post("submitdata.php", {
        name: name,
        address: address,
        contact: contact
    });

});
```

Comment: its says that unidentified index. i think the $_POST dont have values or didnt get any value from the table.